# Execute NunitExecution Report Command prompt commands using C# in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have command to generate execution report in command prompt as below format

specflow.exe nunitexecutionreport ProjectFilePath \xslt:XSLT filepath \Out:OutputFilepath.

The above command is working in command prompt and able to generate report.

How can i execute above command using C# via visual studio.

Comment: post build events?

Comment: After building code ,we will get .DLL files .Using That we are running our scripts in nunit.then testresult.xml file will be generated .Using that XML file we will generate html report by manually executing above mentioned in command prompt.we want to automate that manual  execution of above commands